# How many ways are there to add toppings to ice cream?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> At an ice cream shop, in addition to chocolate chips, there are 8
>   different toppings. If a customer wants to add two more toppings in
>   addition to the chocolate chips in how many ways can he do so? Assume
>   that repetition is not allowed.

Now we're supposed to imagine there is a bowl of ice cream and we must consider how many ways are there to add 2 more toppings in addition to the chocolate chips.

I think that this means this is a combinations without repetitions question. As chocolate chips are already chosen, that means we have to choose 2 toppings from 8 available toppings. So this means C(n,r) = C(8,2) = 28.

Am I correct?

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: $8_C_2$ is correct.

Comment: "in addition to chocolate chips" suggests to me that chocolate chips is one of the eight toppings. "Repetition is not allowed", so I'd say you have to choose 2 from the remaining 7 (not 8) toppings. Also, we're not told whether the order of the toppings matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the problem specifically mentions that repetition is not allowed we know that choosing sprinkles then gummi bears is the same as choosing gummi bears and then sprinkles (or whatever the toppings are). Therefore we are looking to find the number of ways we can choose $2$ distinct pairs of toppings from a total of $8$.

We know that the total number of ways to permute $n$ toppings among $k$ choices is   $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$, and plugging in our values gives us $\frac{8!}{(8-2)!}=8\cdot7$. To account for the repetitions that arise from choosing sprinkles then gummi bears, and gummi bears and then sprinkles we divide by $k!$ which in our case is $2!=2$ and we obtain that there are $\frac{8\cdot 7}{2}=28$ ways to pick your toppings.

Hopefully this helps :)